# create home directories after create users

Tags: linux, user-management

I created some users with:

> `$ useradd john`

and I forgot to specify the parameter `-m` to create the home directory and to have the skeleton files copied to each user. now I want to do that, and I don't want to recreate all users (there must be an easier way). so, is there any way to create the user directories and copy the skeleton files?

I thought about creating the directories, chowning them to the corresponding user, copying all the skeleton files and chowning them to the corresponding user. but if there's a command like `useradd -m` that doesn't create the user again, but create the directories, it'd be better.

Comment: Did this happen with a large list of users?

Comment: I had around 10 users with this problem.

Comment: I can't help but feel Rahul has the best answer to your question. Maybe you should revisit your accepted answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This might sound like a silly idea, but if the users aren't actually doing anything, you could do:

`cat /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d : >/tmp/users.list`

Then edit /tmp/users.list to only contain the users you want. Then do:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/users.list`
do
    userdel $i
    useradd -m $i
done
```

However, many Redhat based distributions will create you a new home directory when you first login, providing it is specified in /etc/passwd where the directory should be.

To test that, do an "su - " and see if it does "the right thing". If it doesn't, the above script will work quite nicely, I think.

Comment: yes, it worked, although it created new UIDs and GIDs (but that wasn't a problem). but I forgot to backup the passwords from /etc/shadow, now the users will have to set their passwords again =/

Comment: If he created them recently he might be able to do:

cat /etc/passwd | egrep '^\:[0-9]{4}\:' | cut -f 1 -d : >/tmp/users.list

That should only grab UID of valid users, and not system users.

Comment: What about passwords, do they remain the same? I fear not!

Comment: `for i in $(awk -F: '{print $1 }' /etc/passwd)`

Comment: why use grep or cut with cat and with pipe, why not directly in this way? cut -f 1 -d : < /etc/passwd > passwtmp

Comment: This is a horrible idea, you should avoid deleting users and messing with the /etc/passwd or /etc/group files by hand. It leads to nothing but tragedy. Try the answer with mkhomedir_helper below.

Comment: to look only normal users we can use `getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 >= 500{print $1}'`

Answer (score 146):

Also you can use `mkhomedir_helper`

```
Usage: /sbin/mkhomedir_helper <username> [<umask> [<skeldir>]]
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question without some 10 line script.

Comment: This and the pam answer are the best here, thanks. Never mess with those files by hand if you can avoid it.

Comment: dka@dev-04:/$ /sbin/mkhomedir_helper dka
dka@dev-04:/$ cd 
bash: cd: /home/dka: No such file or directory

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa have you tried it as root e.g. `sudo /sbin/mkhomedir_helper dka` ?  the `/home` directory belongs to the `root` user, and so I would imagine one would have to be root to create a subdirectory thereof.

Answer (score 22):

You will need to create the users directory manually. This requires three steps:

1. Create directory in compliance to `/etc/passwd`, usually there will be already a /home/login entry.
2. Copy initial files from /etc/skel
3. And finally set right permissions:

   - `mkdir /home/YOU`
   - `cd /home/YOU`
   - `cp -r /etc/skel/. .`
   - `chown -R YOU.YOURGROUP .`
   - `chmod -R go=u,go-w .`
   - `chmod go= .`

BTW: I always miss the `-m` option for useradd too. At least Debian based systems should have an `adduser` command, which I recommend over useradd. If you missed `-m` option it might also be worth considering to `deluser` and then recreate the user with proper options.

Edit: Added `-r` for copying also directories.

Comment: Did that: usernameh=myusername; mkdir /home/$usernameh ; cp /etc/skel/* /etc/skel/.* /home/$usernameh; chown -R $usernameh:$usernameh /home/$usernameh; chmod -R 755 /home/$usernameh;

Comment: Personally I don't like the 755 chmod, as it allows users to spy into other users home's. I think each user should explicitly grant access to others. As `public_html` needs at least `x` bit set, I would recommend `chmod 0711` on each home, `public_html` and similar directories as default.

Comment: also, use cp -r for skel, as else it won't copy directories (.ssh).

Comment: On my system (Arch Linux on ARM) `cp -r /etc/skel/.*` recurse back into /etc/ and copies all data from here (/etc/skel/.* matches /etc/skel/.. I expect). The solution from http://superuser.com/a/61619/22153 seem to work: cp -r /etc/skel /home/user (/home/user must not exist before running the command)

Comment: I guess you shell globbing expands `*` with `.` (dot). So `..` is matched. Am I right? Many shells disable this per default, because of such behavior. Which shell do you use?

Comment: @math the best way is `cp -r /etc/skel/. .`

Comment: @math please update, it works in all circumstances mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

```
mkdir -p /home/john
chown john:john /home/john
usermod -d /home/john john
```

That should do the trick I believe

Comment: it says: `usermod: no changes`. and the directory isn't created. it doesn't work either with the `-m` option.

Comment: Alright. I figured out why that didn't work, useradd used to only put $HOME_DIR in /home unless you specified otherwise. It now seems to automatically put it in /home/$USER instead. A cheap way might be to usermod -d /home/john2 -m john then run usermod -d /home/john -m.

Comment: Nevermind that doesn't work either.

Comment: usermod didn't work for this case, but I didn't know about this command, it'll be useful to me :)

Comment: Well at least you learned something new.

Comment: This does work if you add mkdir -p /home/john; chown john:john /home/john; usermod -d /home/john john. The folder is then there and it is that user's home directory.

Comment: You forgot to copy the contents of /etc/skel/ + chown recursive for those new files. usermod wouldn't work since here the directory was registered but not created, usermod won't do anything.

Comment: I submitted an edit, but the problem is that the commands are out of order: the usermod must occur first, then the create and chown.

Answer (score 11):

You can use something like [pam_mkhomedir](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/07/16/creating-home-directories-on-linux-hosts-with-pam_mkhomedir/) to prevent this from ever being an issue with any users in the future. pam_mkhomedir is a PAM module that automatically creates a user's home directory on login if it doesn't exist, and populates it with files from /etc/skel (or whatever skel directory you specify).

This is also a nicely scalable approach because it will continue to solve this problem if you ever switch your user repository over to a directory service like LDAP in the future.

Comment: brilliant! by far the best answer IMHO; not risky, not error prone, system compliant - great! Remark: With Ubuntu 22 the file to edit is "/etc/pam.d/systemd-user" and you just add "session optional pam_mkhomedir.so". So easy! Need it for ssh keys necessary with sshfs user mounts - this is an acceptable solution. Congrats this answer is great!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the home volume was corrupted and I decided just rebuild it from scratch since not much data involved but I want to keep users' login information, so I recreated the home directories manually with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read n x i g c d r
do
  # my system has uid started at 1000, but has nfsnobody at 65534:
  if [[ "$i" -ge 1000 && "$i" -le 65000 && ! -x "$d" ]]
  then
    cp -av /etc/skel "$d"
    chown -R "$i:$g" "$d"
    # may needed in SELinux system:
    restorecon -R "$d"
    # add your chmod as your need:
    chmod -R o-rw "$d"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you edit `/etc/login.defs` to contain

```
CREATE_HOME yes
```

then home directories will be automatically created for any future users, unless you tell the system *not* to do so.

Another option is to use PAM for logins, and use the pam_mkhomedir module to automagically create the homedir on the first login.

Answer (score 2):

Login with the user john and write from a shell:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

That's it! Don't use sudo or su, you don't need root access to create some
directories. From a root account, you can use:

```
sudo -u john xdg-user-dirs-update
```

That way, you will execute the command as john, that can be useful if you made the mistake with more than one user.

Answer (score 0):

My first step after doing a `useradd` is to `su - <user>`.

Creates the home directories, copies skeletons, etc - at least on the CentOS 4 box I do that on most frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the `mkhomedir_helper $USERNAME` command does.

Comment: No value is added by repeating what another answer already explained two years ago.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply edit /etc/passwd. The second to the last field is the user's home directory.

```
greeblesnort:x:1000:1000:greeblesnort,,,:/home/greeblesnort:/bin/bash
```

Comment: They users were already created. The home directories weren't created because he forgot a switch.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the user's home directory, I meant to create the directory and copy the skeleton files to it with the appropriate permissions _after_ the user has been added.

Answer (score -2):

```
usermod -d /home/john john
```

or

```
usermod --home /home/john john
```

and read

```
man usermod
```

;)

Comment: The question is more complex than just that - and already has better answers.